# c++ Queue Pop() : Exception thrown: read access violation. m was nullptr

Tags: c++, queue, buffer, deque

Data is filled without problems. But after doing pop operation 2-3 times,  I'm getting a Exception thrown: read access violation m was nullptr error. What do you think is the reason?

```
    #define bufferSize 60   
    Mat frame1Current;
    vector<Mat> colorImages(4); 
    deque<Mat> frameQueue9001;

        Mat returnImage;

        string gst_pipe[] = {
        "udpsrc port=9001 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false"};

        void func1() {
            videoCap[0] = VideoCapture(gst_pipe[0], CAP_GSTREAMER);

            colorImages[0].create(Size(rsSplitWidth, rsSplitHeight), CV_8UC3);
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                videoCap[0].read(frame1Current);
                frameQueue9001.push_back(frame1Current.clone());

                if (frameQueue9001.size() > bufferSize)
                {
                    colorImages[0] = frameQueue9001.front();
                    frameQueue9001.pop_front();
                    checker9001 = true;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could it be that other threads (that you did not show) are accessing `frameQueue9001` ?

Comment: There are 4 different functions. All in separate thread. They work in parallel. All objects are different.

Comment: according to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/front/) the "no exception throw is Provides the same level of guarantees as the operation performed on the container (no-throw guarantee for standard non-empty containers)."

Comment: The error you report cannot happen in single-threaded code, so another thread (that you did not show) is mucking with your object.

Comment: void CaptureInitialize()
{
    std::thread td1(func1);
    std::thread td2(func2);
    std::thread td3(func3);
    std::thread td4(func4);
    td1.join();
    td2.join();
    td3.join();
    td4.join();
}

I call it as. Listening to 4 different streams

deque<Mat> frameQueue9001;
deque<Mat> frameQueue9002;
deque<Mat> frameQueue9003;
deque<Mat> frameQueue9004;

Comment: When I work in a single thread, its functions are ordered sequentially. I'm not getting an error. Why he might be doing it when he worked in Thread. Am i need to use mutex to prevent data from colliding?

Comment: if you are using mulitithreading then use mutex to lock the queue when you use pop

Comment: Like this ? This way I got an error. 

 if (frameQueue9001.size() > bufferSize && frameQueue9002.size() > bufferSize - 1 && frameQueue9003.size() > bufferSize - 1 && frameQueue9004.size() > bufferSize - 1)
        {
            colorImages[0] = frameQueue9001.front();
            mutex.lock();
            frameQueue9001.pop_front();
            mutex.unlock();
            checker9001 = true;
            i++;
        }

Comment: move your lock before the firs  `front()` and also I recement to use [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) also what the error that are you getting?

Comment: I moved it before "front ()". still i get error -> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF92E864940 (msvcrt.dll) in WASS_GUI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000002D2116A6F70. I'm looking at examples for std :: lock_guard